# How much randomness is required for Gibbs sampling?

Tags: random-generation, gibbs, latent-dirichlet-alloc, parallel-computing

I am attempting to parallelize a program that executes hundreds of calls to [Mallet](https://mimno.github.io/Mallet/)'s getSampledDistribution method, which is essentially an execution of Gibbs sampling over a topic distribution which has been previously built using LDA, each of which executes a thousand iterations. The way this is implemented in Mallet is that the random factor of Gibbs sampling comes from a random seed which is uniformly accessed: this allows multiple executions of my program to retain determinism so long as the order in which the samplings are done is the same. However, the random seed is retained across samplings: that is, the seed is not reset in-between calls to getSampledDistribution, guaranteeing that no two calls will use the same random factors, even if the overall execution does use the same sequence of random factors every time.

This poses a problem for parallelization: in order to parallelize the execution, I would need to give up determinism since different threads may execute in different orders each time, thus accessing the random seed at a different point in its distribution. Determinism in this part of the process is a requirement for my application, so an option I have is to overwrite the random seed at the beginning of each call to getSampledDistribution, effectively forcing every Gibbs sampling process to use the exact same sequence of random factors, i.e. if I use Gibbs sampling a thousand times in my program, every one of them will use the same random factors, e.g. 3, 5, 7, etc., rather than each sampling having its own random factors across the execution.

My question is, would this significantly affect the quality of the results from the sampling process? Given that the process in Mallet already uses an uniform sequence by default, I assume that so long as the random factor is "sufficiently random", then the sampling process will give me good enough results. However, I unfortunately have a weak background in statistics and machine learning, so I want to make sure doing this will not severely impact the process. If more information about my particular application is needed I can provide it, I just did not want to dump unnecessary information here and further complicate the question.

Comment: Nothing prevents me, that is exactly what I would like to do. I just want to make sure that that would not significantly lower the quality of my results, in comparison to the current implementation where the same seed is used for all executions.

Comment: You are using a single seed in a sense, but, with $p$ parallel threads, allocate random generations $u_1,u_{p+1},u_{2p+1},\ldots$ to thread 1, $u_2,u_{p+2},u_{2p+2],\ldots$ to thread 2, and so on.

Comment: I will try doing that, thank you. I was hoping to parallelize it such that all threads are consuming from the same queue, allowing faster threads to "help" the others. Using your suggestion would require each thread to always execute the sampling over the same sequence, meaning that faster threads will die without being able to aid others. Regardless, that would still be much faster than the single-threaded implementation, so thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Say I have an array of 2,000 items to execute sampling over and four threads to do so. If I merely split the problem into four arrays of 500 items, then should one thread execute faster than the other three, it will go idle once it processes its own 500 items. If, instead, all four threads access the same thread-safe 2,000 item queue, then should one thread be faster, it will continue to process after finishing 500 items. However, if I do this, I cannot guarantee the execution order even if each thread has its own random seed, as the threads will effectively be racing each other.

Comment: Each thread can operate indefinitely, independently of the others, so instead of fixing the number of simulations in each thread, the running time can be fixed for all four, which means none will be idle but instead return a variable number of simulations. Using different seeds on different threads is not a good idea.